# Hibernate - java.time.LocalDate cannot be cast to java.util.Date

Tags: java, hibernate, maven

I'm using Maven, Java, and Hibernate to create a simple app

I know there are a couple of duplicates regarding this question but what I want to know is why this error pops up when I'm using the latest version of **org.hibernate.hibernate-core** which is **5.3.4**.

Based on the questions I've read, I shouldn't have to use hibernate-java8 dependency because hibernate-core has builtin java 8 support and hibernate-java8 is deprecated in Maven.

Any idea what's wrong? Here're some snippets

```
service.addPerson("Rob","Thomas",LocalDate.of(1985,5,5));
```

the method declaration would be

```
public Integer addPerson(String firstName, String lastName, LocalDate birthdate){ 

  Session sesh = factory.openSession();
  Transaction trans = null;

try{ 
   tx = sesh.beginTransaction();
   person = new Person(firstName,lastName,birthdate);
   personID = (Integer) session.save(person);
   tx.commit();
} catch (...) {

}
finally{
  session.close(); 
 }

return personID;
}
```

Comment: Please post the full exception stack trace.

Answer (score 2):

You can cast LocalDate to Date

```
Date current = LocalDate.from(Instant.ofEpochMilli(new java.util.Date().getTime())
                        .atZone(ZoneId.systemDefault()));

LocalDate ld = new java.sql.Date( new java.util.Date().getTime() ).toLocalDate();
```

Comment: But I have to change the Person class property from private LocalDate birthDate to private Date birthDate? Because I need to instantiate a person instance and add it...

Answer (score 1):

You have to convert LocalDate to Date. Here in the first part of the code I convert LocalDate to Date and back to LocalDate object. On the second part I convert LocalDateTime to Date and back to LocalDateTime object.

```
public class LocalDateToDate {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        // Convert java.time.LocalDate to java.util.Date and back to
        // java.time.LocalDate
        LocalDate localDate = LocalDate.now();
        System.out.println("LocalDate = " + localDate);

        Date date1 = Date.from(localDate.atStartOfDay(ZoneId.systemDefault()).toInstant());
        System.out.println("Date      = " + date1);

        localDate = date1.toInstant().atZone(ZoneId.systemDefault()).toLocalDate();
        System.out.println("LocalDate = " + localDate);
        System.out.println();

        // Convert java.time.LocalDateTime to java.util.Date and back to
        // java.time.LocalDateTime
        LocalDateTime localDateTime = LocalDateTime.now();
        System.out.println("LocalDateTime = " + localDateTime);

        Date date2 = Date.from(localDateTime.atZone(ZoneId.systemDefault()).toInstant());
        System.out.println("Date          = " + date2);

        localDateTime = date2.toInstant().atZone(ZoneId.systemDefault()).toLocalDateTime();
        System.out.println("LocalDateTime = " + localDateTime);
    }
}
```

Comment: I can see that this converts LocalDate to Date but does it mean I can't use LocalDate for my models? Since I use 'private LocalDate birthdate' as a property of my Person model. So in short, do I have to change my implementation to java.util.Date in the Person.java class?

Answer (score 0):

If you have :

```
public class Person {
    private LocalDate birthdate;
}
```

You may use a converter and use the annotation `@Convert(converter = LocalDateConverter.class)` on the field

---

```
@Converter(autoApply=true)
public class LocalDateConverter implements AttributeConverter<LocalDate, Date> {
    @Override
    public Date convertToDatabaseColumn(LocalDate d){
        return d !=null ? Date.valueOf(d) : null;
    }

    @Override
    public LocalDate convertToEntityAttribute(Date d){
        return d !=null ? d.toLocalDate() : null;
    }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

Your constructor call `new Person(firstName,lastName,birthdate)` takes `java.util.Date`, and not `java.time.LocalDate`. Just change the constructor, and change the data type inside the Person class.